# Piping filename for last create file into imagej does not show image

Tags: bash, unix, pipe, imagej

I have a large directory of images and want to access the most recent one via command line. I want to show it using `imagej`, but the piping of the command does open imagej, but does not open an image:

```
  ls -Art | tail -n 1| imagej
```

is the command I am using. Am I doing sth wrong? I am on a docker image using xubuntu.

If I only use the  `ls -Art | tail -n 1` i get the image:  `1541917543_right.tiff`. Which is shown correctly if I use the imagej command with the filename.

Comment: I think you've got things backwards... try `ls -Art | tail -n 1 | imagej`...

Comment: that still gives the same effect, imagej starts but no image to be seen. If I only call the ls -Art | tail -n 1 part , and then copy the image file it shows up the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a case of needing to use the `--open` option:

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1 | imagej --open
```

Or perhaps try using `xargs`:

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1 | xargs imagej --open
```

There was also a [bug report](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-legacy/issues/89) filed regarding the opening images from cli (legacy version) on github. If the above suggestions don't work maybe post a response over there.

Comment: Thank you, sadly both of the command did not work. I also had to use "-o" instead of --open.

Comment: @Kev1n91: What happens from cli when you just do `imagej somefile`, does the image open?

Comment: Sorry what is meant by cli ? imagej works fine when I give the filename directly, even when I use the command to look for the filename and then use it for imagej it opens

Comment: `cli` = `command-line interface`, in other words your terminal/shell. Maybe show the output of just the command `ls -Art | tail -n 1`, and you could also try using the `-debug` option (eg. `imagej -debug ...`)  while piping the command.

Comment: The debug command was not recognized, I am working on a docker image of xubuntu, maybe this comes with some issues ?

Comment: @Kev1n91: I'm thinking so — read here too: http://imagej.net/Docker#Running_the_UI

Comment: This actually fixed, do you may edit your answer so it is correct?

Comment: @Kev1n91: I'm not clear what you mean, although if you want to put the final command that worked for you in a reply i'll be happy to edit my answer with the updated information.

Comment: That's what I meant ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put the imagej command at the end, you want to pipe the filename into the command

Comment: that gave the same behaviour strangely